# Eliminate repeated columns but keep the ones that are different using AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file like this:

```
bla AAA 111

bla AAA 222

bla AAA 333

ble BBB 777

ble BBB 555

(...)
```

and would like to keep the uniq first and second column values while taking the values from the third column and adding them to the first entry seen in the file. The output would look like this:

```
bla AAA 111 222 333

ble BBB 777 555

(...)
```

Any hints on how to do this with basic unix/awk command lines?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This should work!

```
awk '{if(!dupli[$3]){A[$1"\t"$2]=A[$1"\t"$2] $3"\t"}}END{for(x in A)print x"\t"A[x]}' file
```

Comment: Indeed it does! Thank you so much!